# How to store correctly the non-latin content of my regex matching, in a String

Tags: java, regex, unicode

first post/question here, so first of all many thanks to this community for being my number one java resource for many years already (as a reader). There is hardly anything I can't find a solution for in here, well until with this one.

So, I got a file I need to retrieve some text from, which I open as follows:

```
BufferedReader openFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getPath), "UTF-8"));
```

I am using a very simple Regex pattern:

```
Pattern getAnalyte = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+),");
```

This pattern works as intended in my scenario and it will occasionally match a string that contains non-latin characters, typically greek. No problem so far.

The problem appears when I need to store in a string the content that was matched. It won't work if there are non-latin characters within:

- I cannot print it correctly in both the console and various Swing components, such as a jComboBox, in which I transfer the matched content. It will just show 1 square for each non-latin character of the matched content.
- it always fails an equals() comparison with the exact same string stored from another source, e.g. from a Swing jTable cell.

I have tried storing the regex matched content in all of the following forms:

```
String getNameTry1 = getMatch1.group(1);
String getNameTry2 = new String(getMatch1.group(1).getBytes("UTF-8"));
String getNameTry3 = new String(getMatch1.group(1).getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

None will work, I am always getting gibberish printed out from any of the above strings.
If all characters are exclusively latin (and numbers), everything works of course great and as intended.
I have run out of ideas - am I missing something or is this not supposed to work at all?

Many thanks in advance !

EDIT 15 Dec 2016: I don't mean to just shamelessly bump my question a month+ later, although ok...this is what I am trying to do, so accept my excuses if this isn't acceptable. I will only do this once anyway. 
Thank you very much for your attention once more and please let me know at least if this is a bad question for some reason so that I quit insisting. It looks as a common situation though that anyone could encounter...

Comment: Can you post some sample text?

Comment: Are you sure your file is encoded in UTF-8? Printing squares (or sometimes question marks) usually means the font of your output window does not include the characters being printed

Comment: All strings have the same encoding, so delete getNameTry2 and getNameTry3.  Those will only make things worse.  As for your equals comparison, I suspect you may have strings which look alike, but aren’t alike;  for instance, `"\u00e9"` and `"e\u0301"` look identical on the screen (accented ‘e’ versus ‘e’ folllowed by combining accent).

Comment: @Bohemian , sure, one line may read "Alpha, John, Tango, ...", the next line may read "Αλφα, George, Foxtrot, ...", etc. I can match and print "Alpha" correctly, I can also match "Αλφα" in the next line but it prints as squares and remains unpractical for storage/comparisons etc.

Comment: @Bohemian , my file is just a windows Notepad where I type my testing text, which I am saving normally as e.g. myTestText.txt .

Comment: @Kosmo13 try printing out the `int` value of each character (eg `(int)str.charAt(i)`) at each stage so you can see *exactly* what characters are involved

Comment: @VGR , ok for discarding getNameTry2 and getNameTry3 - I just got those ideas online from similar threads. Now, I am typing "Αλφα" in my jTable and I can print the cell's content correctly. I am typing "Αλφα" in a win Notepad, saving it, retrieving it with Regex, but can't print it correctly. Also it won't be equal to my jTable's "Αλφα", which looks normal since the discrepancy in the print out.

Comment: @ Bohemian , I printed  (int)str.charAt(i) as you suggested and got '65533' for every single char of my matched (non-latin) word.